# Is glue failure on garage door critical?

Tags: garage-door

The frame of my metal garage door has pulled away from the door. I can see in other images on the web that this frame is not always present. Is the frame for structural integrity or for adding and holding insulation?

Each vertical piece of the frame has a L-shaped piece screwed to it and then glued to the door. This glue had failed at each and every location yet the door operates fine and relatively quietly. Do I need to be concerned about this and/or re-glue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is holding the panels in place, besides these failed glue joints?

Comment: Where are you? If this is in hurricane territory, like Florida, then the glue is a critical piece of the hurricane protection. Your garage looks pretty new. Check your builder's warranty.

Comment: Are you sure that's adhesive and not insulating foam? The manufacturer may be insulating all frames in anticipation that some are use for insulated doors.

Comment: FYI, normally when you don't see a frame it's because the door is a double-skinned insulated door (built that way from the factory, not an add-on.)

Comment: I am in Ohio.  I did not purchase the door; I bought the house 4 years ago as-is.  I am wondering the same: if the glue is really a insulating air block between these segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't critical. The adhesive is primarily there to prevent vibration noise during operation and due to wind. The critical structural connections are at the hemmed seams and the screwed points.

That said, I'd raise a warranty claim. Poor quality is poor quality.

Comment: I wonder if the warranty is transferable, if I can even figure out where it came from.

Comment: Noise-wise, it might be beneficial to use glue these back but I can't imagine how I would press the door against these pieces at this point.

Comment: You'd have to brace it from the outside, or maybe they lay flat enough when the door is open.

Comment: Well, the garage was installed in 1999 so a warranty claim is not a legit option. I do appreciate the feedback though!